# Fast way of determining whether two nodes in a JUNG graph are connected by more than one path?

Tags: java, graph-theory, jung

Given two nodes `A` and `B` from a directed JUNG graph, I want to determine whether there is more than one path from `A` to `B` (not necessarely a *shortest* path).

I can think of two approaches only, both very       time-consuming.

1. Retrieve all paths connecting the two nodes (question [Finding all
   paths in JUNG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778176/finding-all-paths-in-jung/14983018#14983018)) and check if there is more than one.
2. Retrieve the shortest path by using the class
   `DijkstraShortestPath`, then break this path and search for the
   shortest path again. If there is still one, it means there were
   multiple paths.
   Note that this also requires to clone the graph, since I do not want to alter the original graph.

How can I do this smarter (i.e. *faster*)?

Comment: Do you want to know whether there is more than one _shortest_ path, or just more than one path?  Further, are you interested in modifications that remove vertices, or just edges?  If you're interested in modifications that remove a vertex, BiComponentClusterer may be of interest: http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/cluster/BicomponentClusterer.html

Comment: Just more than one path.
I'm not sure if to modify the graph is the smartest way to solve this problem, but I will try the `BiComponentClusterer`. Nevertheless, I do not understand why it accepts only an `UndirectedGraph`. Do I need to clone my entire graph to remove all edge directions?

Comment: I'd have to check, but I'll bet that BiComponentClusterer doesn't actually need the "UndirectedGraph" constraint.  Try modifying it so that it takes a Graph and see if it works; it should be an easy change.

Comment: Now that I think about it, it actually makes sense that this class accepts only `UndirectedGraph`. Even if I manage to pass a `DirectedGraph`, the edge direction would be ignored, so I could not use this class to detect _directed_ paths. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself.

My problem has the additional constraint that I only want to check whether there is more than one path *only for two nodes that are directly connected with and edge*. This means that by simply computing the shortest path you will always get this single edge as path.

So, my question can be reformulated as:

**Is there another path connecting the two nodes of an edge, aside from the edge itself?**

The solution is to use a *weighted* shortest path. If we assign a very high weight to our edge of interest, and weight `1` to all the others, then if the minimal distance is lower than our high weight, the answer is **YES**, otherwise **NO**.

Here is the code:

```
public static boolean areThereMultiplePaths(final Edge edge, DirectedGraph<Entity, Edge> graph) {
        Transformer<Edge, Integer> transformer = new Transformer<Edge, Integer>() {
            public Integer transform(Edge otherEdge) {
                if (otherEdge.equals(edge))
                    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                else
                    return 1;
            }
        };

        DijkstraShortestPath<Entity, Edge> algorithm = new DijkstraShortestPath<Entity, Edge>(graph, transformer);
        Double distance = (Double) algorithm.getDistance(edge.getStartNode(), edge.getEndNode());

        return distance < Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
    }
```

Comment: That constraint makes all the difference; wish you'd mentioned that before.  In this context you have a more elegant solution: remove the edge, run Dijkstra, and see whether there is a non-null distance.

Comment: You are right, I only later realized I had that additional constraint. In any case, in my question I already say that this elegant solution is not possible, as I do not want to alter the graph. The only way would be to _clone_ the graph, but I guess that this would make the solution more time-consuming than mine.

Comment: Why is altering the graph such a big deal?  Are there other readers that are looking at the graph while you're running this computation?  (You can put the edge back when you're done with no side effects.)  Side note: 'distance' can be null, so you can get a NPE thrown on your last line in your code as written.

Comment: If I can put the edge back without side effects, then also that solution is a good alternative. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: JUNG itself does not have side effects associated with removing edges.